# String .length() function is not defined

Tags: java, string, eclipse

This is the code that I am using:

```
public void addNode(TreeNode<String> root, String cd, String letter) {

     if (cd.length() == 1)
     { 
       //Do something
     }

}
```

For some reason, when I call cd.length() it is giving me an error saying "the method length is not defined for type String." Does anyone have a solution for this? I am using Eclipse IDE. Also, I am implementing an interface that is the following:

```
public void addNode(TreeNode<T> root, T code, T letter);
```

Comment: Show the class declaration. I bet your class either called `String`, or you have a type variable called `String`. Or you have another class in the same package called `String`.

Comment: public class MorseCodeTree<String> implements LinkedConverterTreeInterface<String>  **LinkedConverterTreeInterface is generic.**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
public class MorseCodeTree<String> implements LinkedConverterTreeInterface<String>
```

is defining a type variable called `String`, which hides the type `java.lang.String`.

Remove the type variable declaration:

```
public class MorseCodeTree implements LinkedConverterTreeInterface<String>
```